Can a positive elementary inductive definition refer to its own stage comparison relation?
This is a cross-post of a question from cstheory.SE

Moschovakis' stage comparison theorem says that the stage comparison relation associated with any positive elementary induction is itself definable by (another) positive elementary induction. But what if we augmented a positive elementary induction by the ability to refer to its own stage-comparison relation, at least with regards to elements that already appear at some prior stage of the induction? Is the resulting least fixed-point still inductive?
Formally: Suppose $\varphi(x,R,S)$ is a first-order formula in a signature $L$ with two second-order variables: a unary relation symbol $S$ and a binary relation symbol $R$. Suppose $R$ and $S$ each only appear positively in $\varphi$ (i.e., under an even number of negations).
I will define ordinal-indexed families of unary relations $S^\alpha$ and binary relations $R^\alpha$ on that structure as follows:

$S^0 := \emptyset$
$R^\alpha(x,y)$ means ``there is some $\iota < \jmath \le \alpha$ such that $x \in S^\iota$, $y \in S^\jmath$, and $y \notin S^\ell$ for any $\ell < \jmath$.''
$S^{\alpha + 1} := \{x:\varphi(x,R^\alpha,S^\alpha)\}$, and
For limit ordinals $\gamma$, $S^\gamma := \bigcup_{\alpha < \gamma} S^\alpha$.

(All definitions are with respect to a fixed implicit $L$-structure)
I claim that the sequence $S^\alpha$ is monotone in $\alpha$. (Note that monotonicity of $R^\alpha$ follows immediately from definition of $R$.) Let's prove by induction on $\beta$ that for all $\alpha < \beta$, $S^\alpha \subseteq S^\beta$. At successor stages ($\beta = \delta + 1$) it suffices to observe that $S^\delta \subseteq S^{\delta + 1}$: if $x \in S^\delta$ then $\varphi(x,R^\alpha,S^\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \le \delta$, so $x \in S^{\delta + 1}$ as both $R$ and $S$ occur positively in $\varphi$. For limit ordinals $\beta$ and $\alpha < \beta$, $S^\alpha \subseteq S^\beta$ immediately by definition of $S^\beta$.
Since $S^\alpha$ is monotone in $\alpha$, there is some least ordinal (the closure ordinal) $\Gamma$ such that $S^\alpha$ stabilizes past $\Gamma$ (i.e., for all $\Gamma \le \alpha < \beta$, $S^\alpha = S^\beta$). At this point, $R^\Gamma$ is just the stage comparison relation associated with this induction.
Question: Is $S^\Gamma$ inductive? I.e., is there a positive elementary $L$-formula $\psi(x,T)$ such that the least fixed-point of $\psi$ is $S^\Gamma$?
(I'd guess that if the answer is yes, then we should be able to find such a $\psi$ that's independent of the underlying $L$-structure, though I have no good reason for that.)
